# Get current route path during static render

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using Next.js (v14/app router) to generate a statically exported. However, in one of my layouts, I have a tab bar that allows switching between pages.

Very basic:

```
<div className="tabs">
    <Link
        href={`/post/${p.slug}`}
        className={true ? 'active' : ''}
    >All wins</Link>

    <Link
        href={`/post/${p.slug}/top`}
        className={true ? 'active' : ''}
    >Top wins</Link>

    <Link
        href={`/post/${p.slug}/stats`}
        className={true ? 'active' : ''}
    >Statistics</Link>
</div>
```

The problem lies with the `active` classname. Is there any way to get the current route of the page, so that I can simply do `className={currentRoute === '/post/${p.slug}/stats' ? 'active' : ''}`.

I know that there's a `usePathname` method, but that seems to be a client component, and seems rather silly to do this on the client side, than during actually rendering the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I see this as a very fitting use case for a client component. This would also allow you to track the currently active segment with ease. Take the following example:

```
"use client";

export default function MyTabComponent({ post }: Props): JSX.Element {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  // make sure to memoize the paths so that the active tab doesn't
  // re-render on every page change
  const paths = useMemo(() => {
    const postPaths = [
      `/post/${post.slug}`,
      `/post/${post.slug}/top`,
      `/post/${post.slug}/stats`,
    ];

    return postPaths.map((path) => ({
      url: path,
      active: pathname === path,
    }));
  }, [pathname, post.slug]);

  // semantic markup for tabs
  return (
    <ul className="tabs">
      {paths.map((path) => (
        <li key={path.url}>
          <Link href={path.url} className={path.isActive ? "active" : ""}>
            All wins
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with this. I suppose my point would be that during export, Next.js already knows what the path is, is this really not exposed by the framework? For now I can do it as a client component, but it just seems to make more sense to do this during export.

Comment: There is no way to get the current pathname inside a page, no. This would be the recommended approach.